# Isogeny between elliptic curves is always bijective?

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny

Isogeny is morphism between elliptic curves which keeps base point.

Then, is every isogeny between elliptic curves bijective?

Let $E1$ and $E2$ be isogenous elliptic curves defined over Fq. Then #E1(Fq) = #E2(Fq) holds, but the isogeny is not always bijective?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, isogenies need not be bijective. For example $[2]$ is an isogeny from any elliptic curve $E$ to itself. Its kernel is the 2-torsion $E[2]$. Therefore it is not bijective whenever $E(\Bbb{F}_q)$ has non-trivial 2-torsion.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is isogeny always surjective?

Comment: At the level of an algebraic closure (in place of $\Bbb{F}_q$) it will be surjective by general algebraic geometry. At the level of a given finite field it obviously cannot be surjective whenever it is not injective because the numbers of points are equal.